# How to serve 2 react apps on nginx with same ip and port

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, ssl, deployment, node.js

I have two applications one is public and another one is admin, I want to serve these two apps on same port but it is not working, below is my configuration file:

build folder for both apps is saved in below directory

/var/www/html/admin/build

/var/www/html/public/build

Configuration file:

```
server{
    listen 80;
    server_name 192.xx.xx.42;
    
   location /public {
    root /var/www/html/public/build;
    index login.html;
   }
   
   location /admin {
      root /var/www/html/admin/build;
      index login.html
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

nginx adds the URI part of URL after the path specified in `root` directive.

This means that when requesting `/public` URI, nginx will look files in `/var/www/html/public/build/public/` directory.

You can change the `root` to `alias`. In that case, the URI part is not appended to the path, only the filename.

Comment: I tried with alias as well, but it is giving 404 error for all the files even if the files are there in the directory...